# Provider does not live long enough

Tags: rust, ethers.rs

Using ether.rs, I'm trying to listen to multiple steams at the same time. To do this, I have multiple steps:

I first receive the provider address as parameter:

```
async fn start(
    &self,
    provider: String,
) {...
```

Then I connect to the provider:

```
    let provider = arc::new(
        provider::<ws>::connect(provider.clone())
            .await
            .expect("failed to connect to provider"),
    );
```

I then start a thread doing some work using a provider clone:

```
    let provider_clone = Arc::clone(&provider);
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        do_something(provider_clone).await;
    });
```

I then create my filters:

```
    let filters: Vec<Filter> = smart_contract
        .iter()
        .map(|(address, topic0)| {
            let topic0: Topic = topics[0].clone().into();
            Filter::new().address(*address).topic0(topic0)
        })
        .collect();
```

And create my streams:

```
    let mut streams = Vec::new();
    for filter in filters {
        let provider_clone = Arc::clone(&provider);

        let stream = provider_clone.watch(&filter).await.unwrap().stream();
        streams.push(stream);
    }
    let combined_stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream::select_all(streams)));
```

Then, I send the streams into a thread. This is what makes the error pop in the "for filter in filters" loop:

```
    let stream_clone = combined_stream.clone();
    let mut handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        listen(&stream_clone).await;
    });
```

From this point, I have an error when I create my streams: In the for loop, I have this error:

rustc: `provider_clone`does not live long enough. borrowed value does not live long enough [E0597]
rustc: argument requires that `provider_clone`is borrowed for `'static`.

and then say that the "provider_clone" is dropped at the end of the loop.

The [`watch` method signature](https://docs.rs/ethers/latest/ethers/providers/struct.Provider.html#method.watch) here.

I expected the `Arc` to solve this issue, as it's create a thread safe reference counting, but for some reason, It does not work. Here is the solution I tried, that did not work:

- making the "provider" string static lifetime: doesn't change anything
- as "watch" is borrowing and not moving, removing the Arc::clone(), and just borrowing the original value. I get the same error, but it tell me that "provider" is dropped at the end of my function instead of at the end of the loop
- Not using Arc at all: same error
- Using `Pin<Arc<...>>` instead: same error